# chef notification after a change in a directory

Tags: directory, chef-infra

What is the best way to make chef trigger a notification after a file changes within a directory structure?

I would like chef to scan the directory recursively for changes. I am not too sure what is the best approach, maintain a checksum or check timestamps within the directory.

My usecase seems quite common, but I could not find an exact match when googling.

My current attempt looks like:

```rb
directory "/tmp/myfiles" do
  notifies :run, "script[myscript]", :delayed
end

script "myscript" do
  interpreter 'bash'
  code        <<-SH
                 echo "hello world"
                 SH
  action :nothing # only run when notified
end
```

And does not print "hello world" as expected if the directory exists.

Comment: I don't think your situation is very common... What exactly are you trying to achieve? Chef doesn't "watch" a file system, you'd need something like guard or watchr for that...

Comment: I get a few config-files for a proprietary system in the vagrant shared folder from some other machines in a small vagrant network. I would like to restart my service using chef-client, but only when the config has changed. I don't' think a file alteration monitor should be used for this.

Comment: Maybe it is not that common after all. An answer would be appreciated though.

Comment: That's something that your host system would watch and then trigger a Vagrant run. Chef can't "watch" files

Comment: Well, I want to optimise the provisioning, so the server does not get restarted if no files are changed. I don't want chef to watch files, just check if there are changes since the previous run.

Comment: If you manage a file using a chef template resource then chef will detect changes. This feature does not apply to a directories contents

Comment: Did you ever get this working? The notify should do what you want.

Comment: Last time I checked, it did not work for me.